# setContentView() deletes elements which have been added with addView()

Tags: java, android, setcontentview

I've 2 layouts on my project. Both have a button to swap between each other using setContentView method. Whenever I swap between these 2 layouts, every UI element I've added using addView() is lost. However static XML elements remains.

Comment: That's because the layout is inflated anew, with all the views specified in the xml when you call setContentView(R.layout.xml), that's happening behind the scenes, and all the dynamically added views will be gone. So you need to add them again after you call setContentView().

Comment: @HedShafran Yes, I know but there must be some other way to solve this.

Comment: The 2 layouts can live on top of each other and you can toggle their visibility. use `GONE` to hide the layout, not `INVISIBLE` If the layouts have clickable elements on them.

Comment: @HedShafran Your answer was the solution for me. You can post it so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: FYI: You are not supposed to call `setContentView()` multiple times - just once in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the layout is inflated anew, with all the views specified in the xml when you call setContentView(R.layout.xml), that's happening behind the scenes, and all the dynamically added views will be gone.

**Optional solutions:**

1. Add the views again after you call setContentView().
2. The 2 layouts can live on top of each other and you can toggle their visibility. use `GONE` to hide the layout, not `INVISIBLE` If the layouts have clickable elements on them.